# emacs gdb tab-completes directory with space instead of /

Tags: emacs, gdb, gud

When I run gdb within emacs (with `M-x gdb`) and I try to tab-complete directory names, it completes with a space instead of a slash. So, for example:

`(gdb) run/mn`

tab-completes to

`(gdb) run /mnt`

when it should tab-complete to

`(gdb) run /mnt/`

If I run gdb outside of emacs, tab-completion works as expected.

I'm running gdb 7.4.1-debian and emacs 23.4.1 on debian testing.

Any help you could give me here would be greatly appreciated; this is really irritating!

Comment: this has been really annoying me as well - will try the fix below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gud-mode` retrieves the list of possible completitions by calling *gdb*'s `complete` command. In your example, the returned list would contain the following (assuming that there's only one directory in your file system that starts with "/mn"):

```
(run /mnt)
```

The first part of each entry in the returned list is cut off, so that the remaining complete-list is

```
(/mnt)
```

As you can see, this entry returned by *gdb's* `complete` command already lacks the trailing slash. Your only hope to fix this would be to either patch *gdb*'s `complete` command, or to patch Emacs' `gud-mode`, by somehow detecting that the completed word is a directory and then appending a slash (and suppressing the auto-insertion of the space character).

But of course, you could simply bind the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to a different completion function, potentially one that falls back on the default `gud-gdb-complete-command`, but perhaps does a different kind of completion when called for.

For this, try putting the following in your .emacs file:

```lisp
(defun my-gud-gdb-setup ()
  (define-key (current-local-map) "\t" 'my-gud-gdb-complete-command))

(defun my-gud-gdb-complete-command (&optional COMMAND PREDICATE FLAGS)
  (interactive)
  (unless (comint-dynamic-complete-filename)
    (gud-gdb-complete-command COMMAND PREDICATE FLAGS)))

(add-hook 'gdb-mode-hook 'my-gud-gdb-setup)
```

This code binds a new function to the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key which first tries to expand the current word as a file, and only if that fails calls the default `gud-gdb-complete-command`.

Comment: I guess the problem with emacs-side intervention will be that it won't work with remote gdb.

Comment: Note the trailing space in the original question. This is the part that drives me crazy, you have to delete the space and type a slash. Why is it adding the trailing space?

Comment: @sligocki It's been too long since I posted this answer but I seem to remember that my solution fixed the trailing slash problem too. Have you tried it? I might be misremembering.